# jQuery Multiple array loop

Tags: jquery

Need a proper solution how to write this expression.

```
var ary1 = ["","",""];
var ary2 = ["","",""];
var ary3 = ["","",""];
var ary4 = ["","",""];
var div;
for(var i=1; i<5; i++){
    div += ("<p id='text'"+i+">"+(ary+i)[0]+"</p>");
}
```

Just looking for a better solution to make it work. Not getting value from ary1, ary2, ary3 and ary4.

Comment: `(ary+i)` throws an error.

Comment: This is a very frequent question. I linked to a recent similar one but if other users have better links, don't hesitate to give them...

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do something with manually writing html out.  How about you tell us what you're trying to do instead?

Comment: Also have quotes in the wrong place here: `"<p id='text'"+i+">"` the singlequote needs to be moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to reference the different arrays in such a manner, storing them in an object would be a very elegant solution.

```
var arrayDictionary = {
  ary1: ["","",""],
  ary2: ["","",""],
  ary3: ["","",""],
  ary4: ["","",""]
};
for(var i=1; i<5; i++){
    div += ("<p id='text'"+i+">"+ arrayDictionary["ary"+i][0]+"</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ary1 = ["","",""];
var ary2 = ["","",""];
var ary3 = ["","",""];
var ary4 = ["","",""];
var div;
for(var i=1; i<5; i++){
    div += ("<p id='text'"+i+">"+eval('ary'+i '[0]')+"</p>");
}
```

Comment: Be wary of using `eval`, as it can be dangerous and is generally [inefficient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: Can you explain why it can be dangerous and inefficient ?

Comment: Sure thing! [Here is a concise explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) - [here is an explanation of how it can be used properly](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/) - and [here you can read about how it's crazy](http://wingolog.org/archives/2012/01/12/javascript-eval-considered-crazy)

Answer (score 0):

Try an array of arrays:

```
ary = [
  ["","",""],
  ["","",""],
  ["","",""],
  ["","",""]
];

var div = '';
for (var i = 0, len = ary.length; i < len; i++) {
    div += "<p id='text'" + i + ">" + ary[i][0] + "</p>";
}
```

Comment: I realize your indices will have changed from 1 - 4 to 0 - 3.  Hope that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

why not use 2D array?

```
    arr=[ary1,ary2,ary3,ary4,ary5];

for(var i=1; i<arr.legnth; i++){
  for (var j=1;j<arr[i].length;j++){
    div += ("<p id='text'"+j+">"+arr[i][j]+"</p>");
  }
}
```